# Display each record as new page in random order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psql

I have spent the last two days trying to figure out how to solve this question but can't seem to find a solution so was hoping someone else could help me.

I am making a basic app that has tests. Each test consists of several questions. I am trying to make it so that when a user selects a test to complete, they are randomly given each of the questions on a new page (they have to select an answer to move on to the next question etc).

Is there any way I can do this with a .each loop in rails?

In my current test_controller.rb I have:

```
def show
    @test = Test.find(params[:id])
    @questions = Question.all
    @question = @questions.sample(5)
end
```

In my questions_controller.rb I have:

```
def show
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @questions = Question.all
    @question = @questions.sample(5)
    # @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  #   @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
  end

  def edit
    @test.questions.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.update(params.require(:question).permit(:answer))
  end
```

and in my questions/show.html.erb I have:

```
<% @question.each do |question| %>
    <h2>Question </h2>
    <p>
      <%= image_tag question.image.url(:medium) %>
    </p>
    <%= form_tag edit_test_question_path do %>
      <%= radio_button_tag :answer, "a" %> a
      <%= radio_button_tag :answer, "b" %> b
      <%= radio_button_tag :answer, "c" %> c
      <%= radio_button_tag :answer, "d" %> d
      <br/>
      <%= submit_tag 'Save', class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

However when I use this, it is currently showing all 5 questions on one page, which means the url is:

http://localhost:3000/tests/2/questions/1%2F5%2F3%2F4%2F2

Which then obviously means that the form_tag isn't working because it is trying to go to http://localhost:3000/tests/2/questions/1%2F5%2F3%2F4%2F2/edit, which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to make it show just one question at a time and loop through all the questions in a random order? I need to be able to save the  user's answer to the question before they move on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create entity called TestSession, and when user enters test session, create set of records on database with QuestionID and empty answer ID. When user clicks next, you updating current record with user's answer. This flow will give you flexibility in defining next question.
Assuming we have 5 records in our test_sessions table, which could look like

```
id | user_id | question_id | answer | currently_shown
```

so in your controller you could retrieve next question as

```
@next_question = @test_session.where(:answer => nil).sample
```

This will guarantee give you random question from collection of un answered

PS: Update

To prevent user update and get new question, you can add 1 more field and fill it with `true` after you got your next random question. And with help of before filter verify if current question should_be shown or not. This might looks abit complicated, but once you understand whole patters, it will be easy.
Also dont forget to make `currently_shown= false` after user answered question

Comment: The downside of this is that user will get a completely random question every time the page loads.  If he doesn't like the question, he can just refresh to get a new one.

Comment: @BroiSatse yeah I see what you mean...is there a way to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `each` for this as for every page you will be making new request to the server and each loop has to be finish before you serve a response.

I would suggest using [wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) for this purpose with a small tweak to randomize steps.

The way wicked works is that you have all the logic in a single controller. Normally, the new action is responsible for setting up the models you are going to work on by storing its id in a session. We'll do similarly, but instead we pick some questions at random and store those ids in a session. The second step is to force wicked to use this array in the session instead of hardcoded steps.

So your controller would look sth like:

```
class MyTest < ApplicationController

  include Wicked::Wizard
  before_action :set_steps, only: [:show, :update]
  before_action :setup_wizard, only: [:show, :update]

  def new
    # Generate list of questions and store them in a session
    session[:question] = Question.order('RAND()').limit(5).pluck(:id)
    redirect_to action: :show
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(step)
    # No render_wizard here as we are using same template for all steps
  end

  def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.update(params.require(:question).permit(:answer))
    redirect_to next_wizard_step # you can add validations here as well
  end

  private

  def set_steps
    self.steps = session[:questions]
  end

  def finish_wizard_path
     test_results_path # where to go hen all questions has been answered
  end
```

end

Naturally this is only the top level view, you can add much more logic here including test summary at the end etc.

Using this will ensure that the user cannot change given set of questions once those are picked from the database. Id of the questions will be displayed in the url, however user cannot change it as he will get step not-defined error. If you rather prefer display `1,2,3,4,5` this is also easily doable - keep questions in a session but don't use that array to define steps. Define steps the usual wicked way as `1,2,3,4,5` and in the show and update use `find(session[:questions][step.to_i - 1])` - possiblities are endless.

Also note that with this logic in place you can let user to jump between the questions to correct his previous answers, which is pretty neat.

Comment: I've been trying to implement what you sent with the wicked gem but it's not been working...it can't seem to set the steps and keeps returning with a NoMethodError in the the controller saying undefined method 'first' for nil:NilClass -> it's pulling this from code in the wicked gem though (redirect_to "#{ wizard_path(steps.first)}#{query_string || ' ' }"